# ereg_replace to remove all non-alphanumerics is skipping square brackets

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following code that should strip all non-alphanumeric characters (excluding hyphens) from some text.  It somehow misses square brackets somehow, however.

```
ereg_replace('[^A-z0-9-]', '', strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$title)))
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake and wrote `A-z` instead of `a-z`. `A-z` encompasses the `[` and `]` characters.